# OpenLayers: I need to find out, onUnselect, if user has clicked another feature or empty screen

Tags: openlayers

When the event onUnselect is fired, I need to know where (or what) the user has clicked.

I the best case scenario, there would be an event handler called onClickOut or something.

But I don't see it.

Can someone suggest some solution or work around or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
            renderers: renderer
        });
        vectors.events.on({
            'featureselected': function(feature) {
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = this.selectedFeatures.length;
            },
            'featureunselected': function(feature) {
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = this.selectedFeatures.length;
            }
        });
```

not taking credit, the entire example is at

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html

you can see it and we can talk about it if there is anythign else you need to do

Comment: nice thanks. I didnt try it out yet, but I think it will work.
i tried to create two new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer1)/2 controls, but it doesnt work that way. So what I did then was use OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([layer1, layer2]) to capture the events on both layers. But your way is probably the best thanks.